# Workflow not Working for Person Account

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have Created one Workflow rule on Opprtunity.

Account ---> Parent Object 
Opportunity ---> Child Object 
if Pan Number field is Changed in Opportunity it will Update Pan number Fields of Account Object ( Means Copy the Pan number Value to Account Pan Number Values )

Workflow Rule
Rule Criteria   ISCHANGED(PAN_Number__c)

Field Update rule
Field to Update Account: PAN Number of Primary Applicant Only

It is Working fine for All Account  Except ' Person Account' RecordType.
I dont know why this is not Working for Specific RecordType of Account ( ie Person Account ). when i Update Pan Number of Person Account Related Opportinity  it become Blank.Plz help me as possible As. 
please fine below Attachments

Thanks You

Follwing Screen Shots

Screen Shots 1 : when Person Account RecordType Related Opportunity's Pan Number is Updated

Screen Shots 2 : when Person Account RecordType Related Opportunity's Pan Number is Updated it Become Blank

Why this Happen with Person Account. I dont know why?? 
There is no trigger on This field because i Create this field 2 day ago.[image]

[image]

Comment: pretty hard to understand your workfow by your description - would be way better if you provide screenshots with your workflow settings.

Comment: Also I would suggest you to set up debug logs, set maximum debug level for workflow and look through debug logs to find if workflow triggers and if so, what happens with them.

Comment: You describe PAN_Number__c as a "Primary Applicant Number". If so, does it have a lookup to a Contact? If so, that would explain why this isn't working for Person Accounts. The Contact and the Account are treated the same when the recordtype is a Person Account. You're creating a circular reference if it's a Person Account record type.